# Prove $\phi$ is injection

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

We define $Hom_{top-k-alg}$ ($\hat{R}$,$A$) to be the set of $k$-algebra homomorphism from $\hat{R}$ to $A$ which are continuous. $\hat{R}$ is the completion  $\hat{R}$ $=$ $k[[x]]$ of $R = k[x]$ with respect to $J$ $=$ ($x$) and $k$ is a field. $A$ is a $k$-algebra and a topological ring. Suppose that $A$ is a Hausdorff. Show that $\phi$ is injective where

$\phi$ : $Hom_{top-k-alg}$ ($\hat{R}$,$A$) $\rightarrow$ $A$; $f$ $\rightarrow$ $f(x)$.

What I have done so far. Suppose that $\phi$ is not injective we are gonna end up to a contradiction about A being a Hausdorff.

My first attempt was since $\phi$ is not injective we can assume that $ker$ $\phi$ $\neq$ $\{$0$\}$ and then try to find $x_1$, $x_2$ $\in$ $A$ such that $\exists$ $U_1$ , $U_2$ open sets with $x_1$ $\in$ $U_1$ , $x_2$ $\in$ $U_2$ with $U_1$ $\cap$ $U_2$ $\neq$ $\varnothing$ .But really didn't work

My second attempt is to go with the uniqueness of the limit in a Hausdorff. Suppose that $x_1$,$x_2$ $\in$ $ker$ $\phi$ with $x_1$ $\neq$ $x_2$ therefore $\phi(x_1)$ $=$ $\phi(x_2)$ $=$ $0$. So if I can find a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n$ $\rightarrow$ $x_1$ and $x_n$ $\rightarrow$ $x_2$ and I got my contradiction so I can assume that $ker$ $\phi$ is a singleton and what is left is to show that the unique element is zero. But I cannot think something about the existence of the sequence and I believe that I haven't completely understand the structure of $\phi$ since we are talking about homomorphisms $ker$ $\phi$ = $f$ with $f=0$.

I am convinced that I have to work with the contradiction but I do miss some thing so I cannot put my thoughts into a better structure so can you please light the things up a little bit? Thank you

Comment: First note that the elements of $\ker(\phi)$ are morphisms $\hat{R}\to A$, not elements of $A$ as you seem to imply in your analysis. The question can be reformulated as: a continuous morphism $k[[x]]\to A$ is uniquely determined by the image of $x$ in $A$.

Comment: It doesn't even make sense to talk about $\ker(\phi)$ as $\operatorname{Hom}(\hat R,A)$ isn't even a group. Just unpack the definitions: $\phi$ is injective iff for all $f,g : k[[x]]\to A$, $f(x)=g(x)$ implies $f(s(x)) = g(s(x))$ for all $s(x)\in k[[x]]$, which you can show using uniqueness of limits and the corresponding property for $k[x]$.

Comment: Can you please tell me how the uniqueness of limits will get me to $f(s(x))=g(s(x))$ it's not that obvious to me?@arkeet